# Invited to interview but no address

Tags: interviewing

I was invited to attend a face to face interview, but the interviewer forgot to send the address. It has been more than 24 hours. Should I wait a bit longer before emailing him? What should the email look like?

Comment: _"I was invited to attend a face to face interview, but the interviewer forgot to send the address."_  So neither you or the interviewer came to the conclusion that a physical location and a certain time needs to be agreed on to actually have a face to face meeting? - That sounds _really_ professional..

Comment: You should call the individual

Comment: This wasn't with UPS, was it?

Comment: No, I would email him immediately. Just a simple sentence of, "Thanks. Can you please provide me the address?"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's no need to wait at all. The email should be short and on point:

> Hi Interviewer,
>
> Could you please send me the address of the location where the interview will take place?
>
> Thank you,
> Daniel

If you suspect there's not enough time for them to respond before the interview, it's also appropriate to call the company or the interviewer directly, if they shared their contact details with you.

Comment: Next time if *essential* information is missing ask for it immediately.

Answer (score 8):

> *Should I wait a bit longer before email him*

No, not at all. Unless they mentioned that they'll be communicating the place of interview later, it's most likely they overlooked that part and that's a mistake. Shoot an email immediately asking about that info, and also try to reach them over phone (if you have one).

Answer (score 3):

I guess you shouldn't have waited at all. It is better to clarify such issues immediately. This fact can speak not only of the inattention of the interviewer, but also of yours.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you do not wait. It shows that you’re proactive, which is a positive quality for you, as an applicant, to possess.

Also, if the interviewer waits until the last minute to send the address, it may be an indicator that you should be hesitant to trust the interviewer, job, or company, depending on the situation. I’ve found that competent interviewers tend to send calendar invites, which include the address, on the day the interview is scheduled.